# Download the replication snapshot file using FTPS

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2014, configuration, transactional-replication

I have two databases for two companies. Company A's database contains domain data. The other company is pulling the data using snapshot replication. We have used FTP to communicate:

1. Created FTP server on IIS in Window Server 2014
2. Added the certificate to the Server
3. Created the replication publisher and given the FTP account information
4. It is working perfectly without the FTP server
5. IIS set the certificate and the required SSL connection now it is not working
6. This data is two company data and we want communication done using FTPS

It is not working, we don't want to use VPN. We got [a link from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms151227.aspx) 
  and it is saying:

> If you use SSL to secure the connections between computers in a replication topology, specify a value of 1 or 2 for the -EncryptionLevel parameter of each replication agent (a value of 2 is recommended). A value of 1 specifies that encryption is used, but the agent does not verify that the SSL server certificate is signed by a trusted issuer; a value of 2 specifies that the certificate is verified. Agent parameters can be specified in agent profiles and on the command line.

So where can I set this `EncryptionLevel=2`?

[image]

This is the test cases to connect to the server:

1. We have changed the Server name during the login ftps://Domain.com
2. Change the port 990 and open the port still not worked

In short, I want to use FTPS for communication.

I can communicate over FTP. I am working on SQL Server 2014.

Comment: It [is clear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/deliver-a-snapshot-through-ftp?view=sql-server-ver15) that FTP snapshot delivery cannot use secure FTP and the vendor recommends using a VPN for security. What you want to accomplish is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, SFTP is a specific port that you specify and the protocol sees the port and negotiates the encryption and shares the public key. It looks like you can use the @ftp_port argument in your publication to specify the appropriate sftp port (usually 22).

[ftp technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146956(v=sql.105).aspx): https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146956(v=sql.105).aspx